# How to sort, append, revese four lines that perform same task?

Tags: python

Can you tell me how to shorten these lines that sort, append and reverse ? As you can see they perform the same task, the only difference is in their name.

Comment: My eyes are going -- are the parameters to the `.append()` calls identical?

Comment: They look identical to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `for` loop:

```
for posts in recent_posts, forum_posts, search_posts, rss_posts:
    posts.append("<li class=" + date + "><a href='" + page2 + post + ".html'>" + string.replace(title, '#', '') + "</a></li>")
    posts.sort()
    posts.reverse()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Rob ! I must wait 10 minutes to mark your comment with green sign.

Comment: That's not what `apply` does, maybe you mean `map`? I wouldn't recommend using it in this case anyway, the `for` loop is much clearer.

Comment: @interjay - You are correct, of course. Where's my coffee? I was thinking of a `map()`-like entity that doesn't create a list of the results.

Comment: You could also use the `reverse` parameter of `list.sort()`, rather than calling `list.reverse()`.  The only difference would be that entries that compare equal would be the opposite way round.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dictionary (although you would probably have to change more code):

```
post_groups = {'recent': [], 'forum': [], 'search': [], 'rss': []}

html_str = ("<li class=" + date + "><a href='" + page2 + post + ".html'>" +
            string.replace(title, '#', '') + "</a></li>")
for posts in post_groups.itervalues():
    posts.append(html_str)
    posts.sort(reverse=True)
```

As you can see, you can use `posts.sort(reverse=True)` to sort in reversed (descending) order.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
posts = [recent_posts, forum_posts, search_posts, rss_posts]
[post.sort(reverse=True) for post in posts]
```